# Converting symbol style set for ArcGIS Desktop for use in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, convert, style

Is there a way to convert a symbol style set for ArcGIS for use in QGIS?

There are symbols used in Incident Command I would like to use in QGIS, but can only find a style set for use in ArcGIS.  The style set I have is saved as a .style file.